# Let $f,g$ be differentiable with $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$. Prove that $f(x)<g(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, derivatives

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x$ belonging to the set of real numbers. Prove that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Any help? Im so confused :P

Comment: Mean Value theorem this.

Comment: Consider $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$

Comment: Hi! please add what you've done, so you can get better responses. Also, like Kris said check the Mean value theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: I definitely think applying the suggestion from Kris to the suggestion of Hagen will take you where you need to go.

Comment: Immense thanks guys !

Comment: Anyone got a different way of proving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $ \displaystyle h(x):= f(x) - g(x), \quad x \in \mathbb R $

The function $h$ is differentiable in $ \mathbb R$ as a difference of differentaible functions, with $ h'(x)= f'(x) -g'(x), \quad  x \in \mathbb R$. So, according to hypothesis we obtain that:

$$ h'(x)= f'(x) - g'(x) < 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R $$

so $h$ is (stricly) decreasing in $\mathbb R$, and therefore for $ x>0$ we have that

$$ h(x) < h(0) $$

Thus, $ \displaystyle f(x) - g(x) < f(0) -g(0)=0 \implies  f(x) <g(x) \quad \forall x> 0$